# How to Filter nested list through URL in Django RestFramework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a course model and insde it I have a categories list … I want to be able to filter the categories 
Here's my serilaizers

```
class CourseSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories =  serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    image = VersatileImageFieldSerializer(
        sizes=[
            ('full_size', 'url'),
            ('thumbnail', 'thumbnail__100x100'),
            ('medium_square_crop', 'crop__400x400'),
            ('small_square_crop', 'crop__50x50')
        ]
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('id','name_a','name_e','short_desc_a', 'short_desc_e','image','categories') 

    def get_categories(self, obj):
          cats = CourseCategories.objects.filter(course=obj.id)
          return CourseCategoriesSerial(cats,many=True).

class CourseCategoriesSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseCategories
        fields = '__all__'
```

and here's the results

```
            "active": 1,
            "creation_date": "2018-02-24",
            "creation_user": 1,
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "active": 1,
                    "creation_date": "2018-02-24",
                    "course": 1,
                    "category": 140,
                    "subcategory": 159,
                    "creation_user": 1
                },
```

I have a course categories model and it's nested in the course serilaizers...my models.py look like:

```
class Course(models.Model):

    name_a = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name_e = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    creation_user = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='creation_user')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'course'


class CourseCategories(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, models.DO_NOTHING)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Lookups', models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='course_category')
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('Lookups', models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='course_sub_category')
    active = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'course_categories'
```

I want to be able to filter the nested list, URL filter.. like `api/course/?categories__category=140`

this my views :

```
class CourseApiView(generics.GenericAPIView,
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseSerial
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ('id','popularity','offered','creation_date')
    filter_fields = ('id','name_a','name_e','short_desc_a', 'short_desc_e','level','price','currency','start_date','end_date','details','language','location','priority','status','visible','image','total_rating','total_raters','popularity','offered','offer_value','active','creation_date','creation_user')
    lookup_field = 'id'
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use any of the following packages,

1.  [django-url-filter](https://github.com/miki725/django-url-filter)

2. [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter)
I think, the first one will more apt for your requirement.  [Follow the instructions](https://github.com/miki725/django-url-filter#overview) and you will get what you are searching for

Comment: yeah I already use it .. but I couldn't have what I wanted .. because "categories" is not a field of the Course model

Comment: if you did it before plz help me because I have a deadline

Comment: If you **properly configured** the *django-url-filter* package, then, try `api/course/?coursecategories=140`

Comment: can you shoe your `views` ?

Comment: add `coursecategories` to `filter_fields` list in your `view`. Then, try the url I already mentioned

Comment: I cannot because it's not a field in the model

Comment: It should possible because `coursecategories` is a **reverse** relation. Apart from that, I tried it

Comment: While I re-creating the issue, I faced many errors, due to many *improper configurations* you already maded

Comment: okay when I enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/course/?coursecategories=140 it returns null

Comment: I tried api/course/?coursecategories__category=140 and it worked …. THAANK YOU so much

Comment: Happy coding ;)